# sssd ldap authentication cannot automount home directories

Tags: openldap, sssd, automount

I have managed to setup ldap authentication. but I do not manage to have the home directories automatically mount when logged in.

the auto.master and auto.home are stored in the ldap.

this is my sssd.conf:

```
    [sssd]
    config_file_version = 2
    services = nss, sudo, pam, autofs
    domains = default

    [nss]
    filter_users = root,ldap,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus,radiusd,news,nscd

    [pam]
    reconnection_retries = 3
    offline_credentials_expiration = 2
    offline_failed_login_attempts = 3
    offline_failed_login_delay = 5

   [domain/default]
   ldap_tls_reqcert = never
   auth_provider = ldap
   ldap_search_base = dc=domain,dc=net
   ldap_group_member = uniquemember
   id_provider = ldap
   ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
   chpass_provider = ldap
   ldap_uri = ldaps://ldapsrv.domain.net
   ldap_chpass_uri = ldaps://ldapsrv.domain.net
   cache_credentials = True
   ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
   entry_cache_timeout = 600
   ldap_network_timeout = 3
   sudo_provider = ldap
   ldap_sudo_search_base = ou=SUDOers,dc=domain,dc=net
   debug_level = 9

   #autofs

   autofs_provider = ldap
   ldap_autofs_search_base = dc=domain,dc=net
   ldap_autofs_map_object_class = nisMap
   ldap_autofs_entry_object_class = nisObject
   ldap_autofs_map_name = nisMapName
   ldap_autofs_entry_key = cn
   ldap_autofs_entry_value = nisMapEntry


   [sudo]
   debug_level = 9

   [autofs]
   debug_level = 9
```

I can login using the ldap credentials do sudo but cannot mount the homedir that are shared by nfs on the ldap server.

it seems it read the auto.master from ldap but fails after... tried ldap and ldaps.

```
lookup_nss_read_map: reading map ldap ldap:nisMapName=auto.home,domain.net
parse_server_string: lookup(ldap): Attempting to parse LDAP information from string "ldap:nisMapName=auto.home,domain.net".
parse_server_string: lookup(ldap): server "(default)", base dn "nisMapName=auto.home,domain.net"
parse_ldap_config: lookup(ldap): ldap authentication configured with the following options:
parse_ldap_config: lookup(ldap): use_tls: 0, tls_required: 0, auth_required: 4, sasl_mech: (null)
parse_ldap_config: lookup(ldap): user: (null), secret: unspecified, client principal: (null) credential cache: (null)
do_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
read_one_map: map read not needed, so not done
mounted indirect on /export/home with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
st_ready: st_ready(): state = 0 path /export/home
st_expire: state 1 path /misc
expire_proc: exp_proc = 140100367800064 path /misc
expire_cleanup: got thid 140100367800064 path /misc stat 0
expire_cleanup: sigchld: exp 140100367800064 finished, switching from 2 to 1
st_ready: st_ready(): state = 2 path /misc
handle_packet: type = 3
handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 582, name testuser, request pid 15127
attempting to mount entry /export/home/testuser
lookup_mount: lookup(ldap): looking up testuser
do_bind: lookup(ldap): auth_required: 4, sasl_mech (null)
get_server_SASL_mechanisms: Can't contact LDAP server
do_bind: lookup(ldap): autofs_sasl_bind returned -1
do_bind: lookup(ldap): auth_required: 4, sasl_mech (null)
get_server_SASL_mechanisms: Can't contact LDAP server
do_bind: lookup(ldap): autofs_sasl_bind returned -1
lookup(ldap): couldn't connect to server default
lookup(ldap): lookup for testuser failed: connection failed
```

this is my ldap entries:

```
dn: nisMapName=auto.home,dc=domain,dc=net
objectClass: top
objectClass: nisMap
nisMapName: auto.home

dn: cn=*,nisMapName=auto.home,dc=domain,dc=net
objectClass: nisObject
cn: *
nisMapEntry: -rw,sync ldapsrv.domain.net:/export/home/&
nisMapName: auto.home

dn: nisMapName=auto.master,dc=domain,dc=net
objectClass: top
objectClass: nisMap
nisMapName: auto.master

dn: cn=/export/home,nisMapName=auto.master,dc=domain,dc=net
objectClass: nisObject
cn: /export/home
nisMapName: auto.master
nisMapEntry: ldap:nisMapName=auto.home,dc=domain,dc=net
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to messages like `lookup(ldap): couldn't connect to server default` your `nsswitch.conf` doesn't use `sss` for `automount`, but the native LDAP connector, `ldap`. Either use `sss` for `automount` or configure automounter to lookup the maps directly.

Comment: I have configured nsswitch.conf to use sss

  `automount:  files sss`

Comment: if it still doesnt work, please upload new logs..

Comment: hello

the automount has been properly setup from the onset.. it is actually done when you run the authconfig command